# Power Query : Split Table Every n Columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have many columns of same table

Table A

| Monthly Plan | Weekly plan | Actual | Monthly_Plan1 | Weekly_plan 2 | Actual_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | E | F |

I want them as :

| Monthly Plan | Weekly plan | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |
| D | E | F |

I can not create a separate table and append it because there are so many columns and I cant create too many tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclRQ0lFyAhHOIMIFRLiCCDel2FgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Monthly Plan " = _t, #"Weekly plan " = _t, #"Actual " = _t, #"Monthly_Plan1 " = _t, #"Weekly_plan 2 " = _t, Actual_3 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Monthly Plan ", type text}, {"Weekly plan ", type text}, {"Actual ", type text}, {"Monthly_Plan1 ", type text}, {"Weekly_plan 2 ", type text}, {"Actual_3", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Split( Record.ToList( _), 3)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom"),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Monthly", "Weekly", "Actual"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Monthly", type text}, {"Weekly", type text}, {"Actual", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

1. Add a custom column

[image]

2. Remove other columns
3. Expand
4. Extract values concatenating with a |
5. Split the column and rename

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about row order this also works

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Combo = List.Split(Table.ColumnNames(Source),3),
#"Added Custom" =List.Accumulate(Combo, #table({"Column1"}, {}),(state,current)=> state & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source, current)),1))
in #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Note: Davids method is faster when tested for large data sets